# Problem with Eloquent : Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I use `postgresql` and i have `three table`

1: **Habilitation**

```
code              - string(225)
code_menu  - string(225) 
code_sub_menu  - string(225) 
name             - string(225)
```

2: **menu**

```
code              - string(225)
name             - string(225)
```

3: **submenu**

```
code              - string(225)
name             - string(225)
```

I want to show **habilitations** with their **menu** and **sub-menu** using Eloquent , when i try :

```
Habilitation::with(['menu','submenu'])->get();
```

i get this error :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer LINE 1: select * from "menu" where "menu"."code" in (0, 0, 0, 0) ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: select * from "menu" where "menu"."code" in (0, 0, 0, 0))
```

My models :

```
class Menu extends Model
{
    protected $table = "menu";
    public $primaryKey = "code";
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'code' => 'string',
    ];

    public function submenu()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SubMenu','code');
    }

    public function habilitation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Habilitation','code');
    }
}

class SubMenu extends Model
{
    protected $table = "submenu";
    public $primaryKey = "code";
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'code' => 'string',
    ];

    public function menu()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\SubMenu','code');
    }

    public function habilitation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Habilitation','code');
    }

}

class Habilitation extends Model
{
    protected $table = "habilitation";
    public $primaryKey = "code";
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'code', 'code_menu','code_sub_menu'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'code' => 'string',
        'code_menu' => 'string',
        'code_sub_menu' => 'string'
    ];

    public function menu()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Menu','code_menu','code');
    }

    public function submenu()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\SubMenu');
    }

}
```

i haven't problem using query builder of laravel but i want to use Eloquent for it.
someone could help me ? or give me some hints ?
thank you in advance

Comment: protected $fillable = [
        'code', ```  ''   ```code_menu','code_sub_menu'
    ];
fixed this 1st

Comment: @KamleshPaul same error

Comment: can u show error

Comment: @KamleshPaul it's the same message , not changed

Comment: Why `code` is the primary key in every model. And the relationship is `hasMany`??

Comment: @TsaiKoga yes checkout my model above

Comment: @kevin73 A primary key is a series of unique values. however, your Menu **has many** Habilitation though 'code', are you sure about that?

Comment: @TsaiKoga I was wrong about that but it doesn't solve the problem too .

Comment: @kevin73 your problem occurs because postgreSQL  cannot compare an integer with a varchar.  `Habilitation::with(['menu','submenu'])->get()`, laravel change it to raw sql. search code in `(0,0,0)`, however, and 0 is integer, your `code` type is varchar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i added `public $keyType = ‘string’;` to resolve this problem .
hints : https://www.tekmx.com/blog/using-non-standard-primary-key-with-eloquent-relations-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to `PostgreSQL`. You need to check for proper type casting or column data types as `PostgreSQL` is strict, and you can see you have type cast your columns to string but in the query it's actually integer. This normally happens when you are referencing `INT` to `VARCHAR` or vice versa.

This

```
select * from "menu" where "menu"."code" in (0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Should actually be

```
select * from "menu" where "menu"."code" in ('0', '0', '0', '0')
```

So I suggest changing your string data type to int for primary & foreign keys.

Comment: it doesn't help me really i guess but how to fix in laravel ?

Comment: For primary & foreign keys use int data type instead of string and remove the type cast from your models.

Comment: so it's not possible to use string data type as primary key ?

Comment: Using string is not recommended, as you ll always be stuck in type cast issues. So it's better to use integer/int for primary & foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Attention developers who use uuid in **PostgreSQL**. If you are using `Trait` in **Laravel**, there is a high probability that you will encounter the same problem.

```
class ShoppingSession extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Uuid;

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'string',
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'total',
    ];

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function shoppingCart(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ShoppingCart::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue using Postgres and a MorphMany relationship.
I solved it by setting `keyType` to `string` in the model that returned the relationship, I did not set it directly to the model because I wanted `keyType` as `integer`.

```
public function merchantOrderable(): MorphMany
{
    $morph = $this->morphMany(OrderModel::class, 'merchant_orderable');
    $morph->getParent()->setKeyType('string');

    return $morph;
}
```